# Elastic search 2.1 : Intersection of aggregations

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregate

I have some sample data in elastic search, which looks like below

```
Data1: {
    "name": "rahul",
    "socialnetwork": "facebook",
    "day":1

}Data2: {
    "name": "rahul",
    "searchengine": "google"
    "day": 1
}Data3: {
    "name": "vivek",
    "socialnetwork": "facebook",
    "day":1
}Data4: {
    "name": "devendra",
    "searchengine": "google",
    "day":2
}Data5: {
    "name": "rahul",
    "socialnetwork": "facebook",
    "day":2

}
```

I need to get aggregations on "name" field, where socialnetwork = "facebook" and searchengine = "google".

As far as I know, we can use two aggregations and get an intersection of aggregations.

**1st aggregation :**

```
    {
    "query": {
        "match": {
            "searchengine": "google"
        }
    },
    "aggs": {
        "searcheng": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "name"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**2nd aggregation :**

```
    {
    "query": {
        "match": {
            "socialnetwork": "facebook"
        }
    },
    "aggs": {
        "socialnet": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "name"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And get the common aggregations (i.e. intersection) from both the aggregations.

But I am not able to get intersection using elastic search. 
I have tried many things: subaggregations doesn't help in this case, significant terms aggregations results are not good enough, filters, pipeline aggregations, but couldn't find a solution.

Above sample data is just a simplified version of a big data, there are more than two filters, around 20 filters.

Answer (score 0):

No,you dont need to have intersection of two aggregations.
The above can be easily achieved using `bool query`.For your desired output you can use `should` clause.

```
{
"query": {
  "bool": {
     "should": [
        {
           "match": {
              "searchengine": "google"
           }
        },
        {
           "match": {
              "socialnetwork": "facebook"
           }
        }
     ],
     "minimum_number_should_match": 1
    }
   },
  "aggs": {
  "searcheng": {
     "terms": {
        "field": "name",
        "min_doc_count" :2
     }
   }
  }
 }
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: bool query doesn't work here, must imposes both the search criterias to be in same document. But one condition is in one document and other condition is in some other document. So above query doesn't give no results.

Comment: Can you please specify the desired output or corresponding sql query for the same?

Comment: Desired output is a list of names, which has searchengine = "google" and socialnetwork = "facebook". Using sql,  have to use inner 'join' :( select name n1, searchengine se  from table1 where searchengine = "google" )  setable  inner join (select name n2, socialnetwork sn from table1 where socialnetwork = "facebook") sntable on setable.n1 = sntable.n2

Comment: As per the data above given by you , do you want following result:  "buckets": [
            {
               "key": "rahul",
               "doc_count": 2
            },
            {
               "key": "devendra",
               "doc_count": 1
            },
            {
               "key": "vivek",
               "doc_count": 1
            }
         ]

Comment: yes, final aggregation should only contain names which are common to both queries

Comment: This change fetches not only rahul, but other names "vivek" and "devendra" too, which are not desired...

Comment: Add "min_doc_count" :2 to the aggregation.That will fetch only those names which have both social network and searchengine. Edited the query.

Comment: Thanks. "min_doc_count" solves the problem for the example I have given in the question. But number of documents matched for a single filter is not just 1, it can vary.If each filter fetches only 1 document for a given name, min_doc_count would help, but that's not the case.

Comment: I have updated the question, with the case I have mentioned in above question. Here {"searchnetwork" : "facebook"} filter matches 2 docs for  "name" = "rahul". "min_doc_count" doesn't work in this case.

Comment: Ohh,That's tricky. Can we use "day" field in your query for above example? Is there some other case left except the one mentioned above?

Comment: Above example generalise's all the cases. All combinations of "searchengine","socialnetwork" and "day" queries are possible.